# Save data in a real-time application using websocket in Django

Tags: python, django, websocket

I developed a Django application to view live heart rate.
For now, I generate the heart rate signal in a Jupyter Notebook and access it in Django using websocket for Python. When the connection with the Websocket closes, I want to record the entire received signal.
How do I save this signal?

My whole project is build on this model : [Real_time_Django_App](https://www.etemkeskin.com/index.php/2021/02/08/real-time-application-development-using-websocket-in-django/)

consumer.py

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer
import json

class DashConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):
    print('==================')
    async def connect(self):
        self.groupname='dashboard'
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.groupname,
            self.channel_name,
        )
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self,close_code,signal):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.groupname,
            self.channel_name
        )   

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        datapoint = json.loads(text_data)
        val =datapoint['value']
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.groupname,
            {
                'type':'deprocessing', #function name to run
                'value':val #value to send function
            }
        )
        print ('>>>>',text_data)

    async def deprocessing(self,event,signal):
        valOther=event['value']
        #@valOther = f'{valOther}'
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({'value':valOther}))
```

Jupyter Notebook

[image: Jupyter Notebook]

I tried to save each point individualy by accessing the Database in the receive function and modifying the instance stored but given the number of points and frequency at which they are send it doesn't seem to be a viable solution. Is it possible to save all the points send one time before closing the websocket ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!